# Xbox UWP WebView not responsive after hiding InputPane

Tags: javascript, c#, xaml, uwp, xbox

I am accessing an html webapp within a WebView in an Xbox XAML app. For context, it was previously a hosted webapp, but leaks while playing video content were causing crashes, which prompted me to use a XAML app with a WebView and a MediaElement.

Initially, my `<input/>` fields were not showing the keyboard (InputPane) when focused and pressing the 'A/ok' button on the controller/remote. Using the following

```
window.Windows.UI.ViewManagement.InputPane
              .getForCurrentView()
              .tryShow();
```

helped show the keyboard on first key press. With my app hosted in the WebView, I had the same problem, but `window.Windows` was not available. The solution seems to be the use the `ScriptNotify` event on the WebView, that itselfs calls the (very similar) following code in the C# portion of the code:

```
Windows.UI.ViewManagement.InputPane.GetForCurrentView().TryShow();
```

So far so good. Now the problem: when hitting the "B/return" button on the controller/remote, the InputPane leaves, and the `<input/>` element is obviously focused since it still shows a blinking text cursor, but the app does not respond to keypresses. I have to press the "B/return" button a second time to regain control on the webapp.

I looked into the InputPane api, and in hacks like focusing the WebView but without success so far.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you please provide your XBox windows 10 OS version and UWP app version?  By testing on build 15063, <input type="text"/> area will show the keyboard by default, why and how you need  show it manually?

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT the OS version is 10.0.15063.4102 - I need to show the keyboard manually since without that line of code, showing the keyboard would need to press the enter key two times.